# Fluctuating revs

Tags: engine, transmission, audi

I have a 2007 Audi s5 4.2 v8. When the engine is cold it drives faultless but as the engine gets warm is where the niggles start showing. When pulling away the revs fluctuate up and down quite rapidly. Then when driving the car jerks in first and second at high revs. It's a manual transmission. I have had spark plugs changed, fuel filter and had it terra cleaned but still no change. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Couple of quick questions - 1) have any error codes been logged? 2) once the fluctuation has started does it only occur while driving or does it happen at idle as well?

Comment: Hi, no there are no fault codes. And the car idles absolutely fine, it is literally only when pulling away. I did a little test today and pulled away using just the clutch with no throttle and the revs were fine. When I add throttle is when it occurs.